# MediaWiki Giving warnings

Tags: php, mysql, mediawiki

I just installed MediaWiki with MySQL on Windows 7. It is running using IIS on localhost:94. Whenever I open the website I get the following two errors :

```
Warning: OutputPage::transformFilePath: Failed to hash 
C:\Users\smehta30\Documents\Website\MediaWiki\mediawiki-1 
.29.0/../resources/assets/wiki.png [Called from 
OutputPage::transformFilePath in 
C:\Users\smehta30\Documents\Website\MediaWiki\mediawiki-
1.29.0\includes\OutputPage.php at line 3804] in 
C:\Users\smehta30\Documents\Website\MediaWiki\mediawiki-
1.29.0\includes\debug\MWDebug.php on line 309


Warning: md5_file(C:\Users\smehta30\Documents\Website\MediaWiki\mediawiki-
1.29.0/../resources/assets/wiki.png): failed to open stream: No such file or 
directory in C:\Users\smehta30\Documents\Website\MediaWiki\mediawiki-
1.29.0\includes\OutputPage.php on line 3802
```

Since I am new to this and this was installed using the default MediaWiki installation can you please point to what I have done wrong?

The second error points to file not found. How do I correct it? Specifically which file in dir.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `Documentroot` directory, file `LocalSetting.php`

change `forward slash "/"` to `backslash "\"` on this line

```
$wgLogo = "$wgResourceBasePath\resources\assets\wiki.png";
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!. I was not able to find a solution till now. This fixed this issue.

 However a new one emerged 
Warning: Header may not contain more than a single header, new line detected in \mediawiki-1.29.0\includes\WebResponse.php on line 46
Main Page

From what I have been able to gather this is regarding a space in DB on URL but I am not sure how to fix it (or if this is the issue). Any Ideas?

Comment: I was getting the header warning too until I doubled up the slashes, so I have this:

`"$wgResourceBasePath\\resources\\assets\\wiki.png"`

 but this got me moving in the right direction. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Just above the line you changed the `/` to `\` it says:

```
## The URL path to the logo.  Make sure you change this from the default,
## or else you'll overwrite your logo when you upgrade!
```

change it to:

```
$wgLogo = "resources\assets\wiki.png";
```

Ultimately, you will probably remove wiki.png and insert your own graphic. When you do, don't forget to update again.

Answer (score 0):

I have replaced the variable `$wgScriptPath = null;` in the `LocalSettings.php`. 
That helped.